# How to import local dependency in yarn

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg

I have 2 projects:

- ProjectA: a Vue.js frontend project
- ProjectB: a js module I want to use as library in Project A

I builded correctly ProjectB and then: `yarn link`

I added in `package.json` of ProjectA the dependency `"ProjectB":"1.0.0"`
then in ProjectA root `yarn link ProjectB`

Still when I try to import ProjectB:
`import {Stuff} from 'ProjectB'`
the build of the Vuejs project fails with this error (which it seems unrelated, but the import cause it):

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors 
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: No ESLint configuration found.
    at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:268:39)
    at Config.getConfigHierarchy (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:192:43)
    at Config.getConfigVector (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:299:21)
    at Config.getConfig (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:342:29)
    at processText (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:181:33)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:690:40)
    at lint (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:263:17)
    at transform (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:237:18)
    at /nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:127:18
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/nodejs/wrapper_project/vuejs_frontend/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:31:14)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

What am I missing?

Those issues seems related:

- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxtjs.org/issues/124
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2948

Comment: That's an ESLint error.

Comment: yes, why it is thrown only if I import my lib (and obviously the build fails)?